# Possible to use pagename inside get_template_part?

Tags: get-template-part, templates

I'd like to grab the current page name and pull that specific template part per page. This way I can just set up a generic tier-1 template that calls in a secondary section based on the current page's title (without having to use a bunch of conditional statements). So, it'd look like this...

```
<?php get_template_part( 'section', '$pagename' ); ?>
```

Pulling in the file: **section-pagename.php** (eg., **section-about.php**).

Is this possible? I wonder if anyone has used this approach. I think it'd be a really efficient way of templating.

Answer (score 2):

I see no reason for this to not work technically, only you don't need those single quotes around variable.

But practically why not just use `page-{slug}.php` or other template option from [hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Page_display)?

Comment: Ah, you're right. It works without the quotes. Thank you! I appreciate it!

I wanted to break up specific secondary areas on pages without creating unique page templates for each of 10-12 pages. Basically, on a magazine-style layout, I want to extend the page past the content entry area.

So, for instance, I'll have a page-tier1.php file that defines the inner header and subnav and then generically links to a template_part that pulls in a content area specific to that page. That secondary section pulls in unique content for the 10-12 pages without having to hard-code each call.

Comment: I agree with swartsr: if the only difference between the Pages is what happens in one specific part of the template, then I would go with `get_template_part( 'section', $pagename )`. If degrades gracefully to `section.php` if the `section-pagename.php` doesn't exist, and minimizes duplication of code.